# Transfer polygons coordination to a format which PostgreSQL can understand

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, import, postgis

I'm using Django with PostGIS and I'm trying to import some data in my Postgres SQL. I have a geometry(Polygon, 4326) column in my database:

```
poly            | geometry(Polygon,4326) | not null
```

Now I want to import some CSV data to my database:
This is my data:

```
poly, district_number
"((51.356568, 35.765461), (51.356589, 35.765382), (51.356461, 35.76536), (51.356441, 35.765429), (51.356436, 35.765446), (51.356408, 35.765561), (51.356537, 35.765582), (51.356566, 35.76547), (51.356568, 35.765461))", 2
"((51.356568, 35.765461), (51.356589, 35.765382), (51.356461, 35.76536), (51.356441, 35.765429), (51.356436, 35.765446), (51.356408, 35.765561), (51.356537, 35.765582), (51.356566, 35.76547), (51.356568, 35.765461))", 3
....
```

And I'm using this command:

```
COPY get_house_info_house(poly, district_number)
FROM '/tmp/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "((" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
CONTEXT:  COPY get_house_info_house, line 2, column poly: " 
((51.356568, 35.765461), (51.356589, 35.765382), (51.356461, 
35.76536), (51.356441, 35.765429), (51...."
```

I think Postgres doesn't recognize the poly column format.I can transfer my data to any format like GeoJson or any other format But the problem is how to transfer it to a format which Postgres can understand it.

Also in similar questions, I found "ST_GeomFromGeoJSON" but I don't know how to use it in a CSV import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In COPY data, you may use the [EWKT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromEWKT.html) format for geometry values, with the SRID at the beginning.

Example (verbatim; in the context of a CSV file, the field would be surrounded by double quotes):

```
SRID=4326;POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))
```

See https://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html or [PostGIS `COPY` geometry with SRID?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330803/postgis-copy-geometry-with-srid)  for more.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're treating your input as CSV, so the commas in the polygon data are being treated as delimiters for the row and it's therefore receiving too many values.  Such data should be quoted.  You should also use round brackets instead of square ones for polygon values.

Also, the data is in the wrong order for the `COPY` command.  Swap `district_number` and `poly` in the `COPY` command.

Your data will need to be converted to look like this:

```
poly, district_number
"((51.356568, 35.765461), (51.356589, 35.765382), (51.356568, 35.765461))", 2
"((53.365689, 35.765461), (51.356589, 35.765382), (53.355689, 35.765461))", 3
```

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.

Comment: I'm sorry about the quotes. I've already had quotes in my CSV file and I just forgot to write it in my question. And about []. I replaced all []s with () and I still get the same error. I also updated my question.

Comment: I've also noticed you need to swap district_number and poly in the COPY command as your data doesn't appear in that order in your file.  I've updated my answer with this suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you are right. my previous error was because of the order of poly and district_number. Now I get the error of polygons format

Comment: Does your data definitly match the format I gave an example of in my answer? I get the following, with data.csv containing the data as shown in my example previously:
`postgres=# CREATE TABLE get_house_info_house (district_number int, poly polygon);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# COPY get_house_info_house(poly, district_number)
postgres-# FROM 'C:\Temp\data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
COPY 2`

Comment: It doesn't work because you are using the `polygon` type while the OP has `geometry(polygon)`, which is a completely different storage format

Comment: Yes, I misread the type being used. Thanks. In that case, the value in the CSV file would need to look like: "POLYGON((51.356568 35.765461, 51.356589 35.765382, 51.356461 35.76536, 51.356441 35.765429, 51.356436 35.765446, 51.356408 35.765561, 51.356537 35.765582, 51.356566 35.76547, 51.356568 35.765461))"

Comment: Thanks. I think the format has worked but now I'm getting this error: ERROR:  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)
CONTEXT:  COPY get_house_info_house, line 2, column poly: "POLYGON((51.356568 35.765461, 51.356589 35.765382, 51.356461 35.76536, 51.356441 35.765429, 51.35643..." Is there any documents for the syntax?